# Registering a cloud data source as global table in Databricks without copying

Tags: apache-spark, azure-storage, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Given that I have a Delta table in Azure storage:

```
wasbs://mycontainer@myawesomestorage.blob.core.windows.net/mydata
```

This is available from my Databricks environment. I now wish to have this data available through the global tables, automatically loaded to all clusters and visible in the "Data" section.

I could easily do this through copying:

```py
spark.read\
  .load("wasbs://mycontainer@myawesomestorage.blob.core.windows.net/mydata")\
  .write.saveAsTable("my_new_table")
```

But this is expensive, and I would need to run it occasionally (structured streaming would help, however). **But is it possible to register the source as a global table directly, without having to copy all files**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CREATE TABLE USING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using) statement in a databricks notebook cell:

```sql
%sql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.my_new_table 
  USING DELTA 
  LOCATION "wasbs://mycontainer@myawesomestorage.blob.core.windows.net/mydata"
```

Table *my_new_table* should appear in your default database in databricks data tab.

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thanks :-)